# Get selected value from COMBO BOX using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, combobox

What I'm trying to do is get the selected `x-combo-list-item`, **Partner** from the `x-combo-list`.
How would I do so? Please help. Thank you.

Please refer to my jsfiddle for code reference. --> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rolu/MkA4T/)

----------------New Question------------------

Does .each() automatically run when if "Partner" is selected?

Comment: The simple way: compare item test with the string "Partner": http://jsfiddle.net/MkA4T/26/

Comment: Works great, change has been update. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/littlefyr/H6yeJ/

JQuery allows you to select based on the content of the element. So you simply use selectors to do what you want:

```
$('.x-combo-list-item:contains("Partner")').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('You have selected Partner!');
    commonFunction($this);
});

$('.x-combo-list-item:not(:contains("Partner"))').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('You have not selected Partner!');
    commonFunction($this);
});

function commonFunction(item){
    // do Ajaxy stuff
};
```

This fails when you start changing the text (like when you have to translate the text). In this case you simply add a constant value to the tags and use attribute selectors:

```
$('.x-combo-list-item[data-val=pnr]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('You have selected Partner attribute wise!');
    commonFunction($this);
});

$('.x-combo-list-item[data-val!=pnr]').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('You have not selected Partner attribute wise!');
    commonFunction($this);
});
$('.x-combo-list-item:not([data-val=pnr])').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('You have not selected Partner alternative attribute wise!');
    commonFunction($this);
});
```

You also can combine those with `.x-combo-selected` and `:not(.x-combo-selected)` in order to handle selected items differently.

If you're adding items via code (or even as a matter of principle) you should delegate the events to a relevant ancestor:

```
$('.x-combo-list-inner')
.on('click', '.x-combo-list-item:contains("Partner")',function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('You have selected Partner! Again');
    commonFunction($this);
}).on('click', '.x-combo-list-item:not(:contains("Partner"))', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    alert('You have not selected Partner! again');
    commonFunction($this);
})
```

Comment: The down side of the content selector is that it matches if the value appears anywhere in the text rather than matching the whole value. so it would also apply if the text was "Not A Partner", not necessarily an issue for the questioner, but worth remembering in general. data-* attribute selection is definitely a more reliable approach

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to `alert` when the user clicks on the `div` which contains the text partner?

```
$('.x-combo-list-item').click(function() {   
    if ($(this).text() === "Partner") {
        alert('You have selected Partner!');

        // Fire your ajax call here
        /*
        $.post('handler.php', {data: data : {even: 'more data'}}, function(data), 'json');
        */
    }
});
```

You had a call to retrieve `data-item` which doesn't exist, so I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: When I inspect elements on the code, it doesn't have data-item. What you have is exactly what I'm looking for since there is no way to get the value from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('#ext-1111 div').each(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).html() == "Partner") {
    alert("This is Partner")
  }
});
```

Regards

Comment: Does .each() automatically check if "Partner" is selected?

Comment: No, thats not its purpose. Its used to iterate through each `<div>` element in the field with the `ext-1111` id.

Answer (score 0):

$('id if box').val('Partner') ;
This will do.